# paintBorder overridden method not getting called

Tags: java, overriding

I have the following piece of code,

**CustomBorderFactory.java**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class CustomBorderFactory extends EtchedBorder {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width,
            int height) {
        System.err.println("Painting here");
        int w = width;
        int h = height;

        g.translate(x, y);

        g.setColor(etchType == LOWERED ? getShadowColor(c)
                : getHighlightColor(c));
        g.drawRect(0, 0, w - 2, h - 2);

        g.setColor(etchType == LOWERED ? getHighlightColor(c)
                : getShadowColor(c));
        g.drawLine(1, h - 3, 1, 1);
        g.drawLine(1, 1, w - 3, 1);

        g.drawLine(0, h - 1, w - 1, h - 1);
        g.drawLine(w - 1, h - 1, w - 1, 0);

        g.translate(-x, -y);
    }

    public static Border createEtchedBorder(Color black, Color red) {
        return new EtchedBorder(black, red);
    }
}
```

The problem is , the overridden paintBorder is not getting called.

In my test code ,

```
JPanel panel = new Jpanel();
panel.setBorder(CustomBorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.black,Color.red));
```

Why the **paintBorder** method in **CustomBorderFactory** class is not getting called. (I can say by the sys.err is not getting printed) though its overridden and it still calls the super class method.

Am new to java. Please help!

Comment: is this actually overriden? can you show the parent method definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method returns a plain `EtchedBorder` :

```
public static Border createEtchedBorder(Color black, Color red) {
        return new EtchedBorder(black, red);
    }
```

What you want is returning an instance of your custom class :

```
public static Border createEtchedBorder(Color black, Color red) {
        return new CustomBorderFactory(black, red);
    }
```

Note that the name of your class is confusing, you should create a `CustomEtchedBorder` class extending `EtchedBorder`, then a real factory class `CustomBorderFactory`, which would return an instance of `CustomEtchedBorder`when you call `createEtchedBorder()`.

Comment: But how can i make sure to call the overridden paintBorder method.

Comment: As soon as you provide your custom Border with its custom paintComponent method, the overriden method will be called.